# Reactor Java Flux vs Mono

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have following scenario to implement.
Get the list of jobs by user Id, iterate jobs and then get account entry by attribute and finally update to account.

Method definition

```
Mono<Void> execute(List<String> users)
```

Jobs Dao returning Mono<List>

```
Mono<List<JobInfo>> getJobsByUser(String user)
```

```
class JobInfo {
   String user;
   String account;
}
```

Getting account is returning Mono list,

```
Mono<List<Account>> getAccounts(String account)
```

I'm struggling to do this using Mono no blocking way. I tried to do this using the block but getting

```
block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-
```

```
public Mono<Void> execute(List<String> users) {
   users.forEach(user -> {
    jobDao.getJobsByUser(user).block().stream().forEach(job -> {
      accountDam.getAccounts(job.getAccount()).block().forEach(acc -> {
        // update account
      });
    });
   
   });

   return Mono.empty().then();

}
```

Comment: `I tried to use Flux and iterate users to get accounts. But method is finish executing before running this.` where is the code? we are not going to write the code for you and do your job, were is the learning experience in that?

Comment: @Toerktumlare my apologies. I updated the question with the code.

Comment: @Delantha Your approach is more imperative rather than reactive. Try to reimplement it without the use of the `block()` method. This might help you: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which-operator

Comment: I would suggest you go through the ”getting started guide” in the reactor documentation before asking on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you need the following flow:

```java
public Mono<Void> execute(List<String> users) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(users)
        .flatMap(user -> getJobsByUser(user))
        .flatMapIterable(jobs -> jobs)
        .flatMap(job -> accountDam.getAccounts(job.getAccount()))
        .flatMapIterable(accounts -> accounts)
        .flatMap(account -> updateAccount(account))
        .then();
}
```